# List all indexes on ElasticSearch server?

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I would like to list all indexes present on an ElasticSearch server. I tried this:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/
```

but it just gives me this:

```json
{
  "ok" : true,
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "El Aguila",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "0.19.3",
    "snapshot_build" : false
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

I want a list of all indexes..

Answer (score 625, accepted):

For a concise list of all indices in your cluster, call

```
curl http://localhost:9200/_aliases
```

this will give you a list of indices and their aliases.

If you want it pretty-printed, add `pretty=true`:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/_aliases?pretty=true
```

The result will look something like this, if your indices are called `old_deuteronomy` and `mungojerrie`:

```json
{
  "old_deuteronomy" : {
    "aliases" : { }
  },
  "mungojerrie" : {
    "aliases" : {
      "rumpleteazer" : { },
      "that_horrible_cat" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @paweloque answer *now* looks like it's the correct solution; seems cleaner. `curl http://localhost:9200/_stats/indexes\?pretty\=1`

Comment: My 2 cents for a plain (non-json) list: `curl -s localhost:9200/_aliases?pretty=true | awk -F\" '!/aliases/ && $2 != "" {print $2}'`

Comment: For Elasticsearch 6.5 either hit the `/stats` endpoint, or the health endpoint with param `_cluster/health?level=indices`

Comment: curl http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v worked for me (on Elastic 6.2.4)

Comment: this answer is way out of date and should be updated

Comment: I don't know what is out of date but did exactly what I needed as of 2022 on LTS ECK.

Answer (score 185):

Try

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'
```

It will give you following self explanatory output in a tabular manner

```
health index    pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow customer   5   1          0            0       495b           495b
```

Comment: Adding a pipe to sort made this easy to see what was going green. Also the store.size changing indicated additional progress.

Comment: you can also select and order columns adding e.g. &h=health,index as well as sort with &s=health:desc

Comment: Be careful when using this command, it may crash your cluster!!!

Comment: @babis21 care to explain ?

Comment: @FlorianCastelain to be honest I cannot find the resources now. It's been some time since I tried to deal with this issue. I remember that there was a note in the docs but I cannot see it anymore (perhaps it was in some other resource). Bottom line was that the _cat API triggers some expensive operations in the cluster. We have a very busy cluster and in our case the cluster crashes when I call _cat/indices. Same happens for _cat/nodes. We just stopped using it, we have many problems with ES and we are in a process of replacing it. For the record, we face this issue with ES version 5.6.

Comment: @Florian just came across this comment: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/high-cpu-usage-while-bulk-indexing/135023/7 from an old thread, in case it helps

Comment: This is the current correct answer. If you are using the curl command above exactly, remember that curl defaults to http. Depending on your configuration you may have to use `curl 'https://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'`

Answer (score 39):

You can query `localhost:9200/_status` and that will give you a list of indices and information about each. The response will look something like this:

```
{
  "ok" : true,
  "_shards" : { ... },
  "indices" : {
    "my_index" : { ... },
    "another_index" : { ... }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you just want to know list of index names then this approach is too much and slower. Better use - `GET /_stats/indexes`

Comment: @asyncwait I'd recommend `/_stats/indices` since it's the correct plural and also the key used in `/_status` and in `/_stats`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a valid URL anymore on version 5.6.

Comment: API endpoint has changed to `_nodes/stats` and `_nodes/status` @KimberlyW

Comment: Deprecated in 1.2.0.

Comment: "invalid_index_name_exception" in v. 7

Answer (score 32):

The _stats command provides ways to customize the results by specifying the metrics wished. To get the indices the query is as follows:

```
GET /_stats/indices
```

The general format of the `_stats` query is:

```
/_stats
/_stats/{metric}
/_stats/{metric}/{indexMetric}
/{index}/_stats
/{index}/_stats/{metric}
```

Where the metrics are:

```
indices, docs, store, indexing, search, get, merge, 
refresh, flush, warmer, filter_cache, id_cache, 
percolate, segments, fielddata, completion
```

As an exercice to myself, I've written a small elasticsearch plugin providing the functionality to list elasticsearch indices without any other information. You can find it at the following url:

http://blog.iterativ.ch/2014/04/11/listindices-writing-your-first-elasticsearch-java-plugin/

https://github.com/iterativ/elasticsearch-listindices

Comment: Doesn't work: `"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
                "reason": "request [/_stats/indices] contains unrecognized metric: [indices]"`

Comment: @IvanYurchenko I've implemented my elasticsearch plugin long time ago. Very possible that the APIs have changed since and it doesn't work anymore.. Best is to use the '_aliases' command. It will also provide information about all indices in elasticsearch.

Comment: illegal argument exception

Answer (score 31):

I use this to get all indices:

```
$ curl --silent 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_cat/indices' | cut -d\  -f3
```

With this list you can work on...

#### Example

```
$ curl -s 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices' | head -5
green open qa-abcdefq_1458925279526           1 6       0     0   1008b    144b
green open qa-test_learnq_1460483735129    1 6       0     0   1008b    144b
green open qa-testimportd_1458925361399       1 6       0     0   1008b    144b
green open qa-test123p_reports                1 6 3868280 25605   5.9gb 870.5mb
green open qa-dan050216p_1462220967543        1 6       0     0   1008b    144b
```

To get the 3rd column above (names of the indices):

```
$ curl -s 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices' | head -5 | cut -d\  -f3
qa-abcdefq_1458925279526
qa-test_learnq_1460483735129
qa-testimportd_1458925361399
qa-test123p_reports
qa-dan050216p_1462220967543
```

**NOTE:** You can also use `awk '{print $3}'` instead of `cut -d\  -f3`.

#### Column Headers

You can also suffix the query with a `?v` to add a column header. Doing so will break the `cut...` method so I'd recommend using the `awk..` selection at this point.

```
$ curl -s 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v' | head -5
health status index                              pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
green  open   qa-abcdefq_1458925279526             1   6          0            0      1008b           144b
green  open   qa-test_learnq_1460483735129      1   6          0            0      1008b           144b
green  open   qa-testimportd_1458925361399         1   6          0            0      1008b           144b
green  open   qa-test123p_reports                  1   6    3868280        25605      5.9gb        870.5mb
```

Comment: `curl -s 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=index'` will print out just the index name. No need to use shell tricks to filter the column.

Comment: not only can you use awk, you *should* use awk (or else use `tr -s ' '` before `cut` to condense runs of spaces) or else you won't get the index name if the status is `red` because it will be padded with spaces and `cut` treats each individual space as delimiting a new field even if that "field" ends up empty

Answer (score 29):

The simplest way to get a list of only indexes is to use the answer above, with the 'h=index' parameter:

```
curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=index"
```

Answer (score 20):

```
To get all the details in Kibana.
 GET /_cat/indices




To get names only in Kibana.
GET /_cat/indices?h=index
```

Without using Kibana ,You can send a get request in postman  or type this in Brower  so you will get  a list of indices names

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?h=index
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 17):

I would also recommend doing /_cat/indices which gives a nice human readable list of your indexes.

Answer (score 13):

`curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?level=indices'`

This will output like below

```
{
  "cluster_name": "XXXXXX:name",
  "status": "green",
  "timed_out": false,
  "number_of_nodes": 3,
  "number_of_data_nodes": 3,
  "active_primary_shards": 199,
  "active_shards": 398,
  "relocating_shards": 0,
  "initializing_shards": 0,
  "unassigned_shards": 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards": 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks": 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch": 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis": 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number": 100,
  "indices": {
    "logstash-2017.06.19": {
      "status": "green",
      "number_of_shards": 3,
      "number_of_replicas": 1,
      "active_primary_shards": 3,
      "active_shards": 6,
      "relocating_shards": 0,
      "initializing_shards": 0,
      "unassigned_shards": 0
    },
    "logstash-2017.06.18": {
      "status": "green",
      "number_of_shards": 3,
      "number_of_replicas": 1,
      "active_primary_shards": 3,
      "active_shards": 6,
      "relocating_shards": 0,
      "initializing_shards": 0,
      "unassigned_shards": 0
    }}
```

Comment: All the other endpoints did not work for me. Your answer worked! Thx. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204526/cat-indices-gives-all-not-found

Comment: Me too, is this a newer version thing. The main answers seem to work on 2.x but not 6.x

Answer (score 8):

send requtest and get response with kibana,kibana is can autocomplete elastic query builder and  have more tools

[look at the kibana](https://www.elastic.co/kibana)

```
 GET /_cat/indices
```

kibana dev tools

http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dev_tools/console

Answer (score 7):

I'll give you the query which you can run on kibana.

```
GET /_cat/indices?v
```

and the CURL version will be

```
CURL -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v
```

Comment: I think it is the best option for viewing elastic indexes. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 6):

**Accessing the Secured Elastic Search though Curl (Update 2020)**

If the `Elastic Search` is secured, You can use this command to list indices

```
curl http://username:password@localhost:9200/_aliases?pretty=true
```

Comment: It works for me. consider that if your password contains symbol character. before each of them you must insert backslash ( \ ) For example if your password is 12@3 you must type 12\@3

Answer (score 5):

For Elasticsearch 6.X, I found the following the most helpful. Each provide different data in the response.

```
# more verbose
curl -sS 'localhost:9200/_stats' | jq -C ".indices" | less

# less verbose, summary
curl -sS 'localhost:9200/_cluster/health?level=indices' | jq -C ".indices" | less
```

Answer (score 3):

I use the `_stats/indexes` endpoint to get a json blob of data and then filter with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_stats/indexes' | jq '.indices | keys | .[]'

"admin"
"blazeds"
"cgi-bin"
"contacts_v1"
"flex2gateway"
"formmail"
"formmail.pl"
"gw"
...
```

If you don't want quotes, add a `-r` flag to jq.

Yes, the endpoint is `indexes` and the data key is `indices`, so they couldn't make up their minds either :)

I needed this to clean up these garbage indices created by an internal security scan (nessus).

PS.  I highly recommend getting familiar with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) if you're going to interact with ES from the command line.

Answer (score 3):

You can also get specific index using

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/<INDEX_NAME>"
e.g.   curl -X GET "localhost:9200/twitter"
You may get output like:
{
  "twitter": {
     "aliases": { 

     },
     "mappings": { 

     },
     "settings": {
     "index": {
        "creation_date": "1540797250479",
        "number_of_shards": "3",
        "number_of_replicas": "2",
        "uuid": "CHYecky8Q-ijsoJbpXP95w",
        "version": {
            "created": "6040299"
        },
       "provided_name": "twitter"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more info

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-index.html

Answer (score 2):

`_stats/indices` gives the result with `indices`.

```
$ curl -XGET "localhost:9200/_stats/indices?pretty=true"
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 10,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_all" : {
    "primaries" : { },
    "total" : { }
  },
  "indices" : {
    "visitors" : {
      "primaries" : { },
      "total" : { }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

People here have answered how to do it in curl and sense, some people might need to do this in java.

Here it goes

```
client.admin().indices().stats(new IndicesStatsRequest()).actionGet().getIndices().keySet()
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the best way to list indices + to display its status together with list : is by simply executing below query.

*Note: preferably use Sense to get the proper output.*

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/shards'
```

The sample output is as below. The main advantage is, it basically shows index name and the shards it saved into, index size and shards ip etc

```
index1     0 p STARTED     173650  457.1mb 192.168.0.1 ip-192.168.0.1 
index1     0 r UNASSIGNED                                                 
index2     1 p STARTED     173435  456.6mb 192.168.0.1 ip-192.168.0.1 
index2     1 r UNASSIGNED                                                 
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

here's another way just to see the indices in the db:

```
curl -sG somehost-dev.example.com:9200/_status --user "credentials:password" | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep index | grep -v "size_in" | uniq


{ "index":"tmpdb"}

{ "index":"devapp"}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Java API

```
Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder().put("cluster.name", Consts.ES_CLUSTER_NAME).build();
TransportClient client = TransportClient.builder().settings(settings).build().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("52.43.207.11"), 9300));
IndicesAdminClient indicesAdminClient = client.admin().indices();
GetIndexResponse getIndexResponse = indicesAdminClient.getIndex(new GetIndexRequest()).get();
for (String index : getIndexResponse.getIndices()) {
    logger.info("[index:" + index + "]");
}
```

Comment: You could provide some explanation for the code, and make the answer a little bit more readable... [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you're working in scala, a way to do this and use `Future`'s is to create a RequestExecutor, then use the [IndicesStatsRequestBuilder](http://javadoc.kyubu.de/elasticsearch/v1.5.2/org/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/stats/IndicesStatsRequestBuilder.html) and the administrative client to submit your request.

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.{ ActionRequestBuilder, ActionListener, ActionResponse }
import scala.concurrent.{ Future, Promise, blocking }

/** Convenice wrapper for creating RequestExecutors */
object RequestExecutor {
    def apply[T <: ActionResponse](): RequestExecutor[T] = {
        new RequestExecutor[T]
    }
}

/** Wrapper to convert an ActionResponse into a scala Future
 *
 *  @see http://chris-zen.github.io/software/2015/05/10/elasticsearch-with-scala-and-akka.html
 */
class RequestExecutor[T <: ActionResponse] extends ActionListener[T] {
    private val promise = Promise[T]()

    def onResponse(response: T) {
        promise.success(response)
    }

    def onFailure(e: Throwable) {
        promise.failure(e)
    }

    def execute[RB <: ActionRequestBuilder[_, T, _, _]](request: RB): Future[T] = {
        blocking {
            request.execute(this)
            promise.future
        }
    }
}
```

The executor is lifted from [this blog post](http://chris-zen.github.io/software/2015/05/10/elasticsearch-with-scala-and-akka.html) which is definitely a good read if you're trying to query ES programmatically and not through curl. One you have this you can create a list of all indexes pretty easily like so:

```
def totalCountsByIndexName(): Future[List[(String, Long)]] = {
    import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
    val statsRequestBuider = new IndicesStatsRequestBuilder(client.admin().indices())
    val futureStatResponse = RequestExecutor[IndicesStatsResponse].execute(statsRequestBuider)
    futureStatResponse.map { indicesStatsResponse =>
        indicesStatsResponse.getIndices().asScala.map {
            case (k, indexStats) => {
                val indexName = indexStats.getIndex()
                val totalCount = indexStats.getTotal().getDocs().getCount()
                    (indexName, totalCount)
                }
        }.toList
    }
}
```

`client` is an instance of [Client](http://javadoc.kyubu.de/elasticsearch/v1.5.2/org/elasticsearch/client/Client.html) which can be a node or a transport client, whichever suits your needs. You'll also need to have an implicit `ExecutionContext` in scope for this request. If you try to compile this code without it then you'll get a warning from the scala compiler on how to get that if you don't have one imported already.

I needed the document count, but if you really only need the names of the indices you can pull them from the keys of the map instead of from the `IndexStats`:

```
indicesStatsResponse.getIndices().keySet()
```

This question shows up when you're searching for how to do this even if you're trying to do this programmatically, so I hope this helps anyone looking to do this in scala/java. Otherwise, curl users can just do as the top answer says and use

```
curl http://localhost:9200/_aliases
```

Answer (score 1):

I had Kibana and ES installed on a machine. But I did not know the details(at what path, or port) was the ES node on that machine.

So how can you do it from Kibana (version 5.6)?

- Go to *Dev Tools*
- See **Console** section, and run the following query:

`GET _cat/indices`

I was interested in finding the the size of a particular ES index

Answer (score 0):

You can query with Kibana:

```
GET _cat/indices?v&s=store.size:asc&h=h,s,i,id,p,r,dc,dd,ss,creation.date.string
```

To execute from the terminal:

```
curl localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v&s=store.size:asc&h=h,s,i,id,p,r,dc,dd,ss,creation.date.string
```

`s=` indicates sorting.

`h=` specifies the columns to be displayed.

Sample Output:

```
h     s    i                               id                     p r    dc    dd      ss creation.date.string
green open test                            CuIbbN9LSVKGJ2Eu1WkVaA 1 0 28119 28590  66.1mb 2024-03-05T06:18:48.006Z
green open .kibana_task_manager_7.14.0_001 VsooXAwwRRy31gVUV8SHGg 1 0    14 14259  34.4mb 2024-02-27T21:03:04.483Z
green open .geoip_databases                WV4Xqzw2R6-qa9V4gbyXtQ 1 0    36    30  34.1mb 2024-02-27T21:00:14.433Z
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have curl installed on your system, then try this simple command : 
**curl -XGET xx.xx.xx.xx:9200/_cat/indices?v**

The above-mentioned command gives you result in this format : 
[result to fetch all indices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEtbP.png)