# _cat/indices gives _all not found

Tags: elasticsearch

ES version: 2.4.1

I was given a username and password for an Elasticsearch cluster (hosted on elastic.co). When I run:

```
GET /_cat/indices?v
```

it returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "index_not_found_exception",
        "reason": "no such index",
        "index": "_all"
      }
    ],
    "type": "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason": "no such index",
    "index": "_all"
  },
  "status": 404
}
```

Is it because of my assigned user role?

UPDATE:

I tried all the endpoints mentioned in the answers at [list all indexes on ElasticSearch server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426521/list-all-indexes-on-elasticsearch-server) and this one worked:

```
GET /_cluster/health?level=indices
```

But I am at a loss as to why other queries don't work.