# Elasticsearch not recieving input from logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm running logstash where the output is set to elasticsearch on my localhost. However, when I open up elasticsearch, it appears that it did not receive any data from logstash. Logstash parses the csv file correctly, as I can see by the output in the terminal.

I've tried modifying the conf file, but the problem remains. The conf file is below

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/Users/kevinliu/Desktop/logstash_tutorial/gg.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
   sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      columns => ["name","price","unit","url"]
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "localhost"
     index => "gg-prices"
  }
  stdout {}
}
```

When I access localhost:9200/ I just see the default "  "You Know, for Search" display/message from elasticsearch.

Comment: I haven't used ES in quite some time, but IIRC, you'll have to access `localhost:9200/gg-prices` to see your index. Or use Kibana.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17429465/6113627

Comment: How are you testing whether ES has received any data? How is the index configured? Have you tried manually indexing one of the documents into the index by grabbing it from the logstash console output and sending it via a PUT request to ES?