# How to get all urls from google search (first page only) then get the index of a specified url from that list, using C# Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Hey guys using Selenium in C# with NUnit testing and chrome, how would I get all the the main urls (web urls) in a list from the first page of a google search, then get the index number of a specified URL from that list?

Comment: Just click f12 and inspect search result to understand what elements you should search in page. For example, single search result is in div with "g" class. About search inside all results - as I know you can find by class in selenium. It should return list (but it's just assumption). Then just use IndexOf() or foreach loop to get index.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how you know what url you want to search, but here it is. I've added a dictionary method just in case you want to store the index and the url for later usage.

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Selenium
{
    public class Tests
    {
        public IWebDriver driver;


        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver(".");
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestUrlsIndex()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com");

            //accept privacy
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[text()='I agree']")).Click();

            //type something and press Enter
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("Retrieve Index" + Keys.Enter);

            //get all a elements 
            var a_webElements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='g']/div/div/a"));


            //print the index for all
            for (int i = 0; i < a_webElements.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"The index is {i} for the url {a_webElements[i].GetAttribute("href")}");
            }

            //when you know the url and want to return its index
            var index = ReturnIndexOfAnUrl(a_webElements, "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217310/get-index-of-a-row-of-a-pandas-dataframe-as-an-integer");



        }

        //when you want to search the url and return its index
        public int ReturnIndexOfAnUrl(IList<IWebElement> webElements, string searchHref)
        {
            return webElements.ToList().FindIndex(x => x.GetAttribute("href").Equals(searchHref));

        }

        //when you want to store the index and its corresponding url
        public Dictionary<int, string> ReturnIndexAsIndexAndUrlAsValue(IList<IWebElement> webElements)
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < webElements.Count; i++)
            {
                dictionary.Add(i, webElements[i].GetAttribute("href"));
            }

            return dictionary;
        }


        [TearDown]
        public void TearDown()
        {
            driver.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

You should see something like

```
The index is 0 for the url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217310/get-index-of-a-row-of-a-pandas-dataframe-as-an-integer
The index is 1 for the url https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-rows-index-names-in-pandas-dataframe/
The index is 2 for the url https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-index.html
The index is 3 for the url https://thispointer.com/python-find-indexes-of-an-element-in-pandas-dataframe/
The index is 4 for the url https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-rows-index-names-in-pandas-dataframe/
The index is 5 for the url https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-index/
The index is 6 for the url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426521/list-all-indexes-on-elasticsearch-server
The index is 7 for the url https://github.com/MikkelSchubert/paleomix/issues/36
The index is 8 for the url https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/index
The index is 9 for the url https://www.sqlshack.com/gathering-sql-server-indexes-statistics-and-usage-information/
The index is 10 for the url https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/141293/query-to-retrieve-index-details-for-a-particular-column-in-all-tables
The index is 11 for the url https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_index
The index is 12 for the url http://www.bcsea.bt/indexnumber
The index is 13 for the url https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.4752753
```